# EF6 I have GUID for UserId Stored in a table but want to add ApplicationUser to the Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My Application is all fine and within IdentityModels I set each class (table). But I want to show in my Razor View the UserName from AspNetUsers and not the GUID. I currently store the GUID but thats all i'm able to display in the views

I'm thinking there must be a built in easy way to do this - and that I don't need to do any mapping or do i

I'm using EF6 and MVC4.5

Here is my class :

```
public partial class x23BatchImport
{

    public int x23BatchImportId { get; set; }

    public Nullable<DateTime> DateTimeFromFilename { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public decimal? Length { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> StartDateTime { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> StopDateTime { get; set; }

    //public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

}
```

...here is an extract from `IdentityModels.cs`

```
namespace AscendancyCF.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        //public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<AscendancyCF.Models.ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<AscendancyCF.Models.SupplyPointType> SupplyPointTypes { get; set; } ETC ETC
```

.....NB all my tables are declared here then I use `OnModelCreating` to set up relationships some of the time...

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Reference : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/12/06/ef-feature-ctp5-fluent-api-samples.aspx

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    // Configure the 1-1
    modelBuilder.Entity<SupplyPoint>()
                .HasOptional(a => a.SupplyPointAddress)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(u => u.SupplyPointAddressId);
}
```

Comment: What's your setup? Is it the same DbContext as ASP.NET Identity? If different, are you using Code First or DB/Model First?

Comment: I'm using EF6 Code First, all classes I have created under Model then added a line reference IdentityModels. None of the membership tables i.e. AspNetUsers are declared here, I did not think I needed to do this and expected there was a built in method to get the details from the AspNetUsers table. So I just stored / saved the UserId Guid into the tables

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework has a set of model and property **[naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx)** that it uses by default. Currently, it's not able to figure out that `UserId` is a foreign key to an `ApplicationUser`.

If you don't want to add any manual mappings, you have to change your naming. The simplest would be to rename the `ApplicationUser` property to `User`.

```
public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```

When doing your queries, use `Include()` to eager load the `User` property with the matching `ApplicationUser`...

```
// using System.Data.Entity; // add this using to use Include()

var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
var batchImport = context.x23BatchImport
                             .Include(x => x.User)
                             .(x => x.x23BatchImportId == 1)
                             .Single();

var username = batchImport.User.UserName;
```

Your other alternatives are:

- Change `UserID` property to `ApplicationUserId`
- Specify the foreign key in a manual mapping in `OnModelCreating()`
- Specify the foreign key on the model using data annotations